# Gradle not workinng, download location does not

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android Studio is driving me crazy once more.
I have the following error:

```
The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip' does not exist.
```

But the "funny" thing is, the URL works when I click it. So I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Android Studio as Administrator